# Network game connection lost

Tags: openttd

Today I always get a network game connection lost message when I try to join to my multiplayer openttd server.

I checked local / server speed test. The only critical value is the 0.5 MBit/s on upload on the server. Do you know what is the requirement? Or can it be any other couse for this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

OpenTTD will automatically disconnect people if they [take to long joining](https://wiki.openttd.org/FAQ_multiplayer#People_get_disconnected_while_joining.2C_how_to_fix_that.3F), how long it takes before they get disconnected is dependent on the variable `max_join_time` (0-65535 ticks, 30 ticks is a second, roughly 36 minutes at the highest setting).

Try changing `max_join_time` on the server to a higher value, the [default value is 500](http://wiki.openttd.org/Console_Variables).